# How to add text at the end of each line after skipping Last N characters

Tags: linux, vim, sed

I'm on Linux command line and I have log file with following content

```
Subscription Service Shutdown at 9:59PM UTC
Subscription Service Restarted at 11:57PM UTC
```

I want to add date before Time Stamp for every line

```
Subscription Service Shutdown at 01 Oct 2016 9:59PM UTC
Subscription Service Restarted at 01 Oct 2016 11:57PM UTC
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you are trying to add a known string `01 Oct 2016 ` or current date?

Comment: I will be adding known string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

sed -r "s/([0-9]+{1}:[0-9]+{1}[A-Z]{2}.*$)/01 Oct 2016 \1/g" test.txt > new.txt

Where text.txt is your log file and "01 Oct 2016 " is your text and the \1 is the time inserted back in from the group match.

Answer (score 2):

the vim way:

```
:%s/ at /&knownString/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this;

```
 echo "Subscription Service Shutdown at 9:59PM UTC"  | sed "s/at */at $(date '+%Y %b %d') /"
```

Eg;

```
$ echo "Subscription Service Shutdown at 9:59PM UTC"  | sed "s/at */at $(date '+%Y %b %d') /" 
Subscription Service Shutdown at 2016 Nov 08 9:59PM UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to do it in `vim`

1) add string after `at`

```
:%s/at \zs/01 Oct 2016 /
```

2) Find time string of the format `HH:MM` followed by `AM UTC` or `PM UTC` and add string. Add `$` anchor if you need to match only at end of line

```
:%s/\v(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[AP]M UTC)/01 Oct 2016 \1/
```